# Let $V \xrightarrow{\phi} W \xrightarrow{\psi} V$. Show that $\phi$ is injective and $\psi$ is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, covering-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V \xrightarrow{\phi} W \xrightarrow{\psi} V$ be linear maps such that $V\xrightarrow{\psi\phi}V$ is an isomorphism. Show that $\phi$ is injective and $\psi$ is surjective.

So, I know that an isomorphism is both injective and surjective. Surjective meaning that all of $W$ maps onto all of $V$ at least once and injective meaning that the nullspace of the map $V \rightarrow W$ will be only the zero vector.

But, how does one prove this without being given a function?

Comment: Curiously, this link pops up under the Related column on the right hand side: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443686/how-to-show-that-when-the-linear-transformation-phi-psi-circ-phi-e-righ?rq=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$\phi$ is injective** Suppose $x,y\in V$ and $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$. Let $f = \psi\circ\phi$ be the isomorphism. Then $\psi(\phi(x)) = \psi(\phi(y)) = f(x)=f(y)$. As $f$ is invertible, $f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}(f(y)) = x = y$. A linear map is injective *iff* it's 1-1 *iff* its kernel is trivial.

**$\psi$ is surjective** If $\psi$ were not surjective, then $\psi\circ\phi$ would not be surjective — impossible, since that is a a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

This results from a general fact about maps between sets:

> Let $E\overset{f}{\longrightarrow} F\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}G$ be maps. Then

- if $g\circ f$ is injective, $f$ is injective.
- if $g\circ f$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective.

Indeed, if $f$ is not injective, $g\circ f$ can't be injective.

The second asserion results from  $f(E)\subseteq F$, hence $g(f(E))\subseteq g(F)$, so if $g(f(E))=G$, then $g(F)=G$.